# WriteableBitmapExtension crashes app on device

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator, writeablebitmapex

I have added a WriteableBitmapExtension via NuGet to my Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT app. I have functions to capture an image from camera and save it to picture library. I tried rotate captured image before save and I found solution here
[WriteableBitmap crashes program with no message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202683/writeablebitmap-crashes-program-with-no-message). Everything works fine on emulator but when I run my app on Nokia Lumia 630 it crashes few seconds after taking a photo without debbuger message. Can anyone help me with this issue? Here is my code of taking photo:

```
public WriteableBitmap Image
   {
        get
        {
            return this.image;
        }

        set
        {
            this.image = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Image);
        }
    }

private async void TakePhoto()
        {
            using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
            {
                var imgEncodingProperties = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
                var img = BitmapFactory.New(640, 480);
                await this.MediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(imgEncodingProperties, stream);
                stream.Seek(0);
                img.SetSource(stream);
                WriteableBitmapExtensions.DrawLine(img, 10, 10, 300, 300, Colors.Black);
                this.Image = img.Rotate(90); 
                this.TurnOffCaptureMode();
            }  
        }

private void TurnOffCaptureMode()
        {
            this.MediaCapture.StopPreviewAsync();
            this.IsInCaptureMode = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Alternate solution is here.**
 ***1 Open file Picket use build in camera to take picture.***

```
 var openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    openPicker.ContinuationData["Action"] = "SendPicture";
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
    openPicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();

***2. In app.xaml.cs you will get captured image. as below.***


    public void Continue(IContinuationActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    if(args.Kind == ActivationKind.PickFileContinuation)
    {
        var openPickerContinuationArgs = args as FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs;

        // Recover the "Action" info we stored in ContinuationData
        string action = (string) openPickerContinuationArgs.ContinuationData["Action"];

        if(openPickerContinuationArgs.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            // TODO: Get the files here
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO: Write code here to handle picker cancellation.
        }
    }
}
```